# Appropriate Python Exception Class for Missing Settings File

Tags: python, error-handling

**What is the appropriate [python Exception](http://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html) to raise if there is a missing settings file?**

For example, in Django projects, a light-weight way to allow users to define local settings is to add the following snippet to the settings.py file

```
try:
    from local_settings import *
except ImportError:
    # want to add informative Exception here
    pass
```

thus, any local settings override the defaults in settings.py.

Comment: Maybe `EnvironmentError` or `LookupError` or even `RuntimeError`. But why is it important? You can create your own if you care: `class MyCustomErrorThing(Exception): pass`

Comment: That is actually what I am doing at the moment, although I was curious if there was a "better" way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The usual exception for missing files is [*IOError*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#IOError).

You can customize the wording by creating a subclass:

```
class MissingSettingsFile(IOError):
    'Missing local settings file'
    pass
```

Then, use that custom exception in your code snippet:

```
try:
    from local_settings import *
except ImportError:
    raise MissingSettingsFile
```